# What does this sentence in the Facebook Documentation mean?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

"The best practice for what permissions to ask for is that you should only ask for the permissions you need right no."

Is this a typo? I believe "no" should be "now".

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/

Comment: That's a reasonable guess and it makes the sentence make sense.

Comment: I've updated the docs to correct the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it's a typo.
You don't have to, but it's a good practice to ask permissions just before you need them:

- "Never ask for permissions you think you might need in the future. People will be suspicious and may reject your app."

You can find more explanation about that here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/